Access Value of Column in LWC Component HTML Table
I have created generic datatable component where I am passing two attributes
<c-genericdatatable 
    columns={columns} 
    table-data={tableData} 
    onedit={handleEdit} 
    ondelete={handleDelete}>
</c-genericdatatable> 

@track columns = [
        
        { label: 'Name', field: 'Name' },
        { label: 'Type', field: 'Type' },
        { label: 'Main Area', field: 'Main_Area__c' },
        { label: 'Sub Area', field: 'Sub_Area__c' },
        { label: 'Item Description', field: 'Item_Description__c' },
        { label: 'Time Frame', field: 'Time_Frame__c' },
        { label: 'Active Item', field: 'Active_Item__c' }
    ];

    @track tableData = [
        {
            Id: '001',
            Name: 'Record 1',
            Type: 'Type A',
            Main_Area__c: 'Area 1',
            Sub_Area__c: 'Sub Area 1',
            Item_Description__c: 'Description 1',
            Time_Frame__c: 'Frame 1',
            Active_Item__c: 'Yes'
        }]

and I am trying to display values inside HTML Table like following
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <template for:each={columns} for:item="column">
                        <th key={column.field}>{column.label}</th>
                    </template>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template for:each={tableData} for:item="record">
                    <tr key={record.Id}>
                        <template for:each={columns} for:item="column">
                            <td key={column.field}>
                                {record.Id} + {column.field}
                               {record[column.field]}
                                <template if:true={column.isField}>
                             
                                    
                                </template>

However I am getting compilation error as following
Unexpected plugin compilation error: Plugin - lwc, Hook - transform, 

Cause - Invalid expression {record[column.field]} - LWC1038:
Template expression doesn't allow computed property access: Source
can anyone please advise how to access {record[column.field]} value

Unlike Aura, LWC doesn't support accessing elements dynamically. Instead, you have to convert the data to an Array. so you can use it in the template.
get rows() {
  // If we have data and columns...
  if (this.columns && this.tableData) {
    // For each row...
    return this.tableData.map(row => {
      // Convert the record data into an array of objects to iterate over.
      return {
        ...row,
        fields: this.columns.map(column => {
          return {
            field: column.field,
            value: row[column.field]
          }
        })
      }
    });
  }
}

Then, in your template:
<template lwc:if={rows}>
<template for:each={rows} for:item="record">
    <tr key={record.Id}>
        <template for:each={record.fields} for:item="column">
            <td key={column.field}>
                {record.Id} + {column.field} = {column.value}

This is more or less how the standard lightning-datatable component operates, although the real code involves many more lines of code.
